# how to dispose animation controller in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a question like before disposing my controller do i need to call`_controller.stop();`

My code:-

```
AnimationController _controller;
@override
void initState()
{
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700), vsync: this);
    _controller.repeat(reverse: true);
    _controller.forward();
}
```

this animation is for showing a heart just like we tap on like on instagram and then heart increases its size and reduces.

code for tapping on heart button:-

```
onTap: ()=>controlUserLikePost(),
```

function:-

```
controlUserLikePost()
{
   _controller.reset();
   _controller.forward();
}
```

So, my question:-

```
@override
  void dispose()
  {
    _controller.stop();//do i need to call it as well?
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();// and does it matter if i dispose the controller before this line or after this line.
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to stop it before disposing it, unless you want to stop the animation at a certain point. But regarding disposing it safely, just use `_controller.dispose()`.

However, it must be before the `super.dispose()`, not after, this is important.

Comment: And does this also matter for initstate? I mean before and after super.initState()

Comment: You don't always have to use super.initState(), only when you are using @override initState. Thus, put the logic also before super.

Comment: thanks a lot, Could you please tell why its necessary to put logic before super.

Comment: For dispose, I know it's important because you need to be super sure that the controller is completely disposed of before calling super.dispose. As after super dispose is called, it means that the widget and it's logic can be safely removed from the widget tree.  This removal can't be marked as safe, unless controller was indeed disposed of.